# Import qgis.core and tkinter in one application

Tags: python, tkinter, qgis

I try to import `modules:qgis.core` and `tkinter` in one application, but I have a problem `:ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'.`

I add to Path: `C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.1\apps\Python39` and I set `PYTHONPATH` to `C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.1\apps\qgis\python`

[image]

Normally without QGIS installed (when the QGIS PATH in Inv Var is not added) tkinter works fine.

Here is the script:

```
import os, sys, glob
from qgis.core import *
import tkinter
```

Comment: `qgis` uses `PyQt` to create User interfaces.

Comment: unfortunatelly I have created an app in tkinter where I use QGIS and I need that both modules to work in the same code.